# What to do in the absence of a .sln file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx

I'm just starting in the world of C++. I was kind of forced into this because I want to study a Physics simulation. With a lot of effort, I found out that I needed to install Microsoft Visual Studio on my computer in order to edit and compile the source files that are available on GitHub.

However I noticed that some of the authors on GitHub do not include .sln files in their projects, and then I'm unable to open/edit/compile them with Microsoft Visual Studio. Conversely, those projects containing an .sln file and that are meant to run on DirectX are the ones that I was able to compile/execute after making my own modifications.

So... What is lacking in those projects that do not contain an .sln file or that are not meant for DirectX?

Comment: Make your own solution and project then add the files to it. If they use cmake then use that to create the solution and project(s).

Comment: Make your own empty solution (i.e. no projects at all) then add the downloaded project to that solution (File/Add/Existing Project... menu item).

Comment: Can you link the repo?

Comment: Perhaps some authors place CMakeLists.txt in their GitHub repositories.

Comment: VisualStudio can natively work and compile CMake files. Just use "open directory" feature rather than "open solution".

Comment: ***or that are not meant for DirectX?*** There are several other opengl, vulkan that are cross platform and can still work just fine on mswindows.

Comment: ***I noticed that some of the authors on GitHub do not include .sln files in their projects*** These days it's quite common to use CMake to make it easier for people to use their code on different platforms.

Comment: To all of you who have replied, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous build systems in the world, but for the Windows ecosystem there are a few dominate ones.

1. MSBuild (Microsoft Build) is the default build system for Visual Studio. `.vcxproj` files are the Visual C++ project files that use MSBuild, and the `.sln` files are meta-files that organize one or more `.vcxproj` files (or .csproj files for C#).
2. NMake (Microsoft Program Maintenance Utility) is the older 'makefile' build system from Microsoft. It's still around, but has not been updated in many years. Visual Studio can also support nmake-based `.sln/.vcxproj` files, but this has fallen out of favor over time and is all-in-all fairly clunky.
3. MinGW (Minimalist GNU for Windows) has its own 'makefile' build system.
4. CMake is a cross-platform 'meta-make' solution that is used by many platforms including Windows. It can target MSBuild, Ninja, MinGW Makefiles, etc. and a number of other build-systems which is why it's a popular open source and multi-platform solution. Visual Studio and Visual Code both support building with this build system, and you can of course use it from the command-line directly if you want. The presence of a `CMakeList.txt` file indicates this.

> To provide some of the functionality of a '.sln' file for CMake, CMake 3.20 or later supports a `CMakePresets.json` file which makes it much easier to use within the Visual Studio and Visual Code IDEs.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/creating-and-managing-visual-cpp-projects) for more in Visual Studio build. For more on CMake with Visual Studio, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio).

For general background on 'makefiles', see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Makefile).

> My list above is far from complete as there are numerous build systems out there (SharpMake, Meson, FASTbuild, etc.). For a good overview, see [this blog post](https://julienjorge.medium.com/an-overview-of-build-systems-mostly-for-c-projects-ac9931494444).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft uses `.sln` files as a way for Visual Studio to manage projects (files, compilation rules, dependencies, etc.), so it is Microsoft-specific.

Most of C++ projects are not written using Visual Studio however, but use other editors & build systems. Projects that do not have a `.sln` file, could have `CMakeLists.txt` files that can be compiled with CMake (which Visual Studio got support for in recent version), or `meson.build` files to be compiled with meson, `Makefile` for make, you get the point.

There are a lot of build systems & IDEs for C++ because it existed for very long time, and because it is a very popular language (for a good reason) so people created tools that suit their workflow. However, there should not be any differences in code you write (given it conforms to a standard version of C++) regardless of the build system or IDE you choose to use.

Comment: And of course there is also [ninja!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_K6971WmAs)